# Apply filters from multiple checkboxList to filter ListView in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filtering, listviewitem

I have webapplication where there are 1000 of products so there is multiple filter needs to be there. I have total 4 checkboxList. Now my problem is if I apply filter from any of checkboxList then it checks selected value for all column that is specified in query. 
What I want is like below

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price_rang IN ('selectedValueFromCheckBoxList1') And category IN ('selectedValueFromCheckBoxList2')
```

What is happening now

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE price_range IN ('selectedValueFromCheckBoxList2') AND category IN ('selectedValueFromCheckBoxList2')
```

So in this query suppose If I select value First from checkboxList2 then for both the columns it takes that value & result not displaying.

Below is my filter process code

```
Private Sub getResult()
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Dim query As String = "select * from products"

        Dim condition As String = String.Empty
        For Each price As ListItem In priceFilter.Items
            condition += If(price.Selected, String.Format("'{0}',", price.Value), String.Empty)
        Next

        For Each sub_category As ListItem In category.Items
            condition += If(sub_category.Selected, String.Format("'{0}',", sub_category.Value), String.Empty)
        Next

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) Then
            condition = String.Format(" WHERE price_range IN ({0}) and sub_category IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1))
        End If

        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query & condition)
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        products.DataSource = dt
                        products.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your "what I want" and your "what is happening now" look the same to me. Is it a typo?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer see What I want in that ID of checkboxList will be different. & what is happening now in that both the columns gets values from same checkboxList

Comment: @AndrewMortimer suppose I have not applied price_range filter &directly checked on category then query gets made like this SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE price_range IN ('power bank') AND category IN ('power bank') 
but ideally if price filter is not applied then it should go blank till the time it has not applied.

Comment: Set a joiner string variable at the top, and set it to 'where'. After it gets used the first time, set it to 'and' and then use it from then onwards.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Little confusing. Can you post answer?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer can you also help me to structure Like Query instead of IN. Because I have multiple keywords to search from so I need to use Like. This is what structure I need - select * from products where  sub_category Like  '%Aviation%' or sub_category Like '%Real Estate%'

Comment: I think you're pretty close with what you've put in there already.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer this is what I made changes with your code. But it's not showing proper output which I want.. This is what changes I made in your code while looping through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136801/structuring-like-query-in-mysql-vb-net. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option is you're only interested in the checked items.

```
Public Function buildWhereClause() As String

        Dim query As String = "select * from products"
        Dim joiner As String = " "

        Dim condition As String = String.Empty
        Dim priceCondition As String = String.Empty

        For i = 0 To priceFilter.Items.Count - 1

            If priceFilter.Items(i).Selected Then
                Dim price As String = priceFilter.Items(i).ToString
                priceCondition = String.Concat(priceCondition, joiner, String.Format("'{0}'", price))
                If joiner = " " Then joiner = ", "
            End If
        Next

        Dim categoryCondition As String = String.Empty
        joiner = " "

        For i = 0 To categoryFilter.Items.Count - 1
            If categoryFilter.Items(i).Selected Then
                Dim category As String = categoryFilter.Items(i).ToString
                categoryCondition = String.Concat(categoryCondition, joiner, String.Format("'{0}'", category))
                If joiner = " " Then joiner = ", "
            End If
        Next

        Dim whereClause As String = String.Empty
        joiner = " where "
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(priceCondition) Then
            whereClause = String.Concat(whereClause, joiner, String.Format(" price_range IN ({0})", priceCondition)) ' and sub_category IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1))
            joiner = " and "
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryCondition) Then
            whereClause = String.Concat(whereClause, joiner, String.Format(" sub_category in ({0})", categoryCondition))
            joiner = " and "
        End If

        Return String.Concat(query, whereClause)

    End Function
```

Comment: In my  codeOnSelectedIndexChanged I was trying to call sub which is not working with the code you given hence nothing gets affected

Comment: Are you trying to filter as the selection changes? Or on all checked items in the list?

Comment: onSelectedIndexChanged I want to filter

Comment: Updated the answer for this condition.

Comment: By applying filter I got this exception on category selection. : An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_zbifwiqs.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: And this is the point where you start debugging and work out the issue.

Comment: I understand the category filters goes null when I apply price filter that is why it shows exception. But can you tell me how to set that string null or empty to avoid exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115679/discussion-between-andrew-mortimer-and-sun).

Comment: I debugged this & query gets build up perfectly but some how not showing output. I think you are not binding listview with this