# Structuring Like Query in mySQL & VB.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have ListView & multiple filters as checkboxList. Everything working properly but Like clause not coming properly. It is like below

```
select * from products where  category Like '% Apparels, Bluetooth%'
```

But it should be like this

```
select * from products where  category Like '% Apparels%' or category Like '%Bluetooth%'
```

How do I change my code to structure my query properly?

```
Public Function buildWhereClause() As String
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Dim query As String = "select * from products"
        Dim joiner As String = " "
    Dim condition As String = String.Empty
    Dim priceCondition As String = String.Empty

    For i = 0 To priceFilter.Items.Count - 1
        If priceFilter.Items(i).Selected Then
            Dim price As String = priceFilter.Items(i).ToString
            priceCondition = String.Concat(priceCondition, joiner, String.Format("'{0}'", price))
            If joiner = " " Then joiner = ", "
        End If
    Next

    Dim categoryCondition As String = String.Empty
    joiner = " "

    For i = 0 To categoryFilter.Items.Count - 1
        If categoryFilter.Items(i).Selected Then
            Dim category As String = categoryFilter.Items(i).ToString
            categoryCondition = String.Concat(categoryCondition, joiner, String.Format("{0}", category))
            If joiner = " " Then joiner = ", "
        End If
    Next

    Dim whereClause As String = String.Empty
    joiner = " where "
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(priceCondition) Then
        whereClause = String.Concat(whereClause, joiner, String.Format(" price_range IN ({0})", priceCondition)) ' and sub_category IN ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1))
        joiner = " and "
    End If

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryCondition) Then
        whereClause = String.Concat(whereClause, joiner, String.Format(" category Like '%{0}%'", categoryCondition))
        joiner = " and "
    End If

    'If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(brandCondition) Then
    '    whereClause = String.Concat(whereClause, joiner, String.Format(" sub_category in ({0})", categoryCondition))
    '    joiner = " and "
    'End If

    Dim masterClause As String = String.Empty
    masterClause = (query & whereClause)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, What is the difficulty that you are facing currently? What is the final query you are getting?

Comment: @un-lucky please see at beginning of my post The first query I mentioned is what I am getting with my code. And the second query is what I actually want. Can you help me to build up second query with my code?

Comment: You don't answer any of my question, What is the difficulty you are facing with current code, what will be the current value that you are  getting for `query`

Comment: @un-lucky this is what query in output I am getting . select * from products where  category Like '% Apparels, Bluetooth%'

Comment: I have posted an answer below Have you tried that? is that ok for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are getting `categoryCondition="Apparels, Bluetooth"` by looping through `categoryFilter.Items` What you can do here is  Replace that `,` with `%' or category Like '%` then every thing will be cool. consider the following:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryCondition) Then
    whereClause = String.Concat(whereClause, joiner, String.Format("category Like '%{0}%'", categoryCondition.Replace(",","%' or category Like '%"))       
End If
```

Comment: @SUN : Cool Happy to help you